# Count input value of a textbox

Tags: php

I want to count the number of inputed value in a textbox
Example the value of a textbox is 1234567 the count of the value is 7
I want to know whether the inputed value is less or greater or equal than 7
How am i able to do it in php
Thanks

Comment: `strlen($_POST['mytxtbox']);`

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please show some code.

Comment: $number2=count($_POST['number2']);
    if($number2!=7)
    {
    output...
    }

Comment: all given answers were correct guys sorry i can only choose 1 answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the number of characters in your input.
For that you can use the native php function strlen http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php:

```
if( strlen( $_POST['input_name'] >= 7 ){
    // Do something since its equal or greater than 7
} else {
    // Its less than 7
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try `strlen()` will return number of length included space

```
echo strlen($input);
```

for check with 7

```
if( strlen($input) >= 7 ){
```

you can also use or `mb_strlen()` for count **ascii** char

Answer (score 1):

For finding the  number of inputted  value  you can simple use `strlen()`.So it would be

```
strlen($_POST['thetextbox']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps:

1. Send the contents of the textbox using forms to the PHP script.
2. I assume that you named your textbox to **mytxtbox** and you have sent your form content to PHP script using **POST** method.
3. Use the following PHP code,It counts it and saves the characters count to a variable:

   ```
   $count = strlen($_POST['mytxtbox']);
   ```

happy codding,best wishes.